# image crashing form on Xamarin Forms iOS project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS project with a PCL project in Xamarin Forms.
For this question I have ContentPages "Page1" and "Page2".

I am handling images, specifically a logo that is a png file. I have several pages that display the logo, including Page1 and Page2.

I am binding the url to the image in the xaml code-behind cs file like this:

```
string imgUrl = "http://my url/upload/mobile/LOGO_GRAY.png";
logoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(imgUrl));
```

On Page1, the image loads and display as I would expect it to look.
On Page2, where the same image logo is bound in the exact same way in the code-behind, that page immediately crashes the app. If I remove the image from Page2, it loads just fine.

From Page1 to Page2 this is my navigation code in my ViewModel:

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginEntryPage());
```

I need help trying to figure out why one page displays the image fine where the other page crashes when the image is displayed.

Previously I was loading the images from a resource folder in the iOS project but it seems like Page2 had a memory leak causing the crash. I switched to images via Url hoping that it would be "lighter" and not cause memory issues.

Thanks

**EDIT 8/10/2020**
The code behind cs of "Page2" (LoginEntryPage.xaml.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using Atwork.Helpers;
using Atwork.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Atwork
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginEntryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginEntryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new LoginEntryPageViewModel();
            try
            {
                string imgUrl = "http://my url/upload/mobile/ATWORK_LOGO_GRAY.png";
                logoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(imgUrl));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception causing the crash?

Comment: Hi Jason, I don't get an exception in the try/catch wrapping this code while stepping through the code in my view model or the view model binding in the code behind. I also have not been able to see anything while using Xamarin Profiler (I am on a Mac). I have also tried to use Wireshark but could not get that to work too.

Comment: I find it very unlikely that this line is causing a crash, especially if there is no exception.  It may be masking some other issue.  If you are unable to catch it, you might try using appcenter.ms to see if that will generate a crash report.  Of look through the log to see if iOS is reporting anything when it crashes.

Comment: If I removed the image control from xaml and comment out the related lines, the page does not crash. I used appcenter.ms last week and it did not tell me a whole lot. I was probably not using it right.

Comment: without more context it's hard to say.  Does it work if you specify the url in XAML?  Are you doing this in the constructor, or somewhere else?

Comment: I have put the url in the xaml, and then tried the constructor in the code-behind, and then tried the constructor in the view model. None of those work in this particular page, but I have several other pages using the same image (logo) bound from the page class constructor that are working fine and not crashing.

Comment: if you have it in the constructor, is it AFTER the call to InitializeComponent?

Comment: It is after the call

Comment: without more info I can't really give you any additional advice

Comment: Thanks Jason I will see if I can get better diagnostics and comment back

Comment: @Ryan Hi, could you share the `.cs` code of second page? I will check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I added the code to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan If you comment this line code : `BindingContext = new LoginEntryPageViewModel();` , whether the image can show?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT image does not show

Comment: @Ryan Okey , if comment this line, does that will crash the app? In addition , have a try with set `source` for `image` in Xaml to check whether can show. `<Image Source="http://my url/upload/mobile/ATWORK_LOGO_GRAY.png" />`

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT if I comment that line, the app does not crash. If I put the image source string in Xaml, the app crashes. A side note, this is only happening in 1 Content Page. The same image is used in other content pages and they are fine.

Comment: @Ryan Could you collect the crash logs in Output of VS ? If so , share the logs here . I will check that.